# Nested Case Then in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do the following which involves a complex query; 
1. First I try to select the column based on some logic 
2. then based on the value of the selected column a value is selected 
3. finally based on the previous value a logic is applied to get the final value

How can I have the result from 2 in the ELSE of the 3rd Case..Then statement ?

```
CASE 
    CASE 
        CASE 
            WHEN MDC.Network ='I' THEN INNBenefitID ELSE OONBenefitID 
        END
        WHEN 'INNDWO' THEN CASE WHEN DWO.Description IS NOT NULL THEN DWO.Description ELSE MDC.CostShareValue END 
        WHEN 'OONDWO' THEN CASE WHEN DWO.Description IS NOT NULL THEN DWO.Description ELSE MDC.CostShareValue END 
        ELSE isnull(dbo.fn_FormatText(MDC.CostShareValue, CostShareType),'''') 
    END
    WHEN '0%' THEN 'Covered 100%'
    WHEN '$0' THEN 'Covered 100%' 
    ELSE ????
   END
```

Comment: Case expressions, not case statements...

Comment: Please explain the logic that you want and provide examples.

Comment: Could be,that `CROSS APPLY` is your friend...

Comment: this is within an Select statement where I have to select a column conditionally and based on the column value to set some logic and then to do some string conversion on the returned value. Simply I want to return the value of the inner Case..when in the Else of the outer Case expression.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like that? :

```
declare @value varchar(255) = (
                     CASE 
                     WHEN MDC.Network ='I' THEN INNBenefitID ELSE OONBenefitID 
                     WHEN 'INNDWO' THEN CASE WHEN DWO.Description IS NOT NULL THEN DWO.Description ELSE MDC.CostShareValue
                     WHEN 'OONDWO' THEN CASE WHEN DWO.Description IS NOT NULL THEN DWO.Description ELSE MDC.CostShareValue
                     ELSE isnull(dbo.fn_FormatText(MDC.CostShareValue, CostShareType),'''') 
                     END
                   ) 

CASE 
   WHEN '0%' THEN 'Covered 100%'
   WHEN '$0' THEN 'Covered 100%' 
   ELSE @value
END
```

Comment: I cannot do this as this block is within the select statement

Answer (score 0):

Really, really hard to do this right without a schema or sample data.  In the future consider creating a SqlFiddle for us.  But one approach you might consider is using a Common Table Expression (CTE) to define an intermediary structure which you then query.

```
;WITH theCTE AS (SELECT 
    CASE 
        CASE 
            WHEN MDC.Network ='I' THEN INNBenefitID ELSE OONBenefitID 
        END
        WHEN 'INNDWO' THEN COALESCE(DWO.Description, MDC.CostShareValue)
        WHEN 'OONDWO' THEN COALESCE(DWO.Description, MDC.CostShareValue)
        ELSE COALESCE(dbo.fn_FormatText(MDC.CostShareValue, CostShareType), '') 
    END AS foo
FROM 
    bar
)

SELECT 
    CASE  
        WHEN foo IN ('0%', '$0') THEN 'Covered 100%'
        ELSE '' -- Do something with foo --
    END AS finalColumn
FROM 
    theCTE
```